# Import error when using bokeh-server

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I found this example online that shows how to use the `bokeh-server` to deploy an app with an interactive plot.
The problem is that I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mtomas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/bokeh-server", line 7, in <module>
    bokeh.server.run()
  File "/Users/mtomas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 186, in run
    start_server(args)
  File "/Users/mtomas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/__init__.py", line 190, in start_server
    start.start_simple_server(args)
  File "/Users/mtomas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/start.py", line 58, in start_simple_server
    configure_flask(config_argparse=args)
  File "/Users/mtomas/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/configure.py", line 76, in configure_flask
    imp.load_source("_bokeh_app", script)
  File "slider.py", line 12, in <module>
    from bokeh.client import push_session
ImportError: No module named client
```

After I type in

```
bokeh-server --script slider.py
```

The content of `slider.py` is the following

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

from bokeh.browserlib import view
from bokeh.document import Document
from bokeh.models.glyphs import Line
from bokeh.models import Plot, DataRange1d, LinearAxis, ColumnDataSource, Grid, Legend
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput, HBox, VBox, Dialog

from bokeh.client import push_session

document = Document()
session = push_session(document)

xs = sy.Symbol('x')
expr = sy.exp(-xs)*sy.sin(xs)
order = 1

def taylor(fx, xs, order, x_range=(0, 1), n=200):
    x0, x1 = x_range
    x = np.linspace(float(x0), float(x1), n)

    fy = sy.lambdify(xs, fx, modules=['numpy'])(x)
    tx = fx.series(xs, n=order).removeO()

    if tx.is_Number:
        ty = np.zeros_like(x)
        ty.fill(float(tx))
    else:
        ty = sy.lambdify(xs, tx, modules=['numpy'])(x)

    return x, fy, ty

def update_data():
    x, fy, ty = taylor(expr, xs, order, (-2*sy.pi, 2*sy.pi), 200)

    plot.title = "%s vs. taylor(%s, n=%d)" % (expr, expr, order)
    legend.legends = [
        ("%s"         % expr, [line_f_glyph]),
        ("taylor(%s)" % expr, [line_t_glyph]),
    ]
    source.data = dict(x=x, fy=fy, ty=ty)
    slider.value = order

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], fy=[], ty=[]))

xdr = DataRange1d()
ydr = DataRange1d()

plot = Plot(x_range=xdr, y_range=ydr, plot_width=800, plot_height=400)

line_f = Line(x="x", y="fy", line_color="blue", line_width=2)
line_f_glyph = plot.add_glyph(source, line_f)
plot.add_layout(line_f_glyph)

line_t = Line(x="x", y="ty", line_color="red", line_width=2)
line_t_glyph = plot.add_glyph(source, line_t)
plot.add_layout(line_t_glyph)

xaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')

yaxis = LinearAxis()
plot.add_layout(yaxis, 'left')

xgrid = Grid(dimension=0, ticker=xaxis.ticker)
ygrid = Grid(dimension=1, ticker=yaxis.ticker)

legend = Legend(orientation="bottom_left")
plot.add_layout(legend)

def on_slider_value_change(attr, old, new):
    global order
    order = int(new)
    update_data()

def on_text_value_change(attr, old, new):
    try:
        global expr
        expr = sy.sympify(new, dict(x=xs))
    except (sy.SympifyError, TypeError, ValueError) as exception:
        dialog.content = str(exception)
        dialog.visible = True
    else:
        update_data()

dialog = Dialog(title="Invalid expression")

slider = Slider(start=1, end=20, value=order, step=1, title="Order:")
slider.on_change('value', on_slider_value_change)

text = TextInput(value=str(expr), title="Expression:")
text.on_change('value', on_text_value_change)

inputs = HBox(children=[slider, text])
layout = VBox(children=[inputs, plot, dialog])
update_data()
document.add_root(layout)
session.show(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("\npress ctrl-C to exit")
    session.loop_until_closed()
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably comes from your `bokeh` version.

```
import bokeh   
bokeh.__version__
```

It seems that `bokeh.client` is in v0.11. You can check https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/wiki/Porting-guide:-new-Bokeh-server

Comment: thanks, I am actually using v0.10. How can I upgrade? `pip install` doesn't do the job.

Comment: It's a development version (the last version released is 0.10). The following command should work `pip install -e git://github.com/bokeh/bokeh.git@0.11.0dev2#egg=bokeh`

Comment: If `pipe` doesn't work, you can clone the repository and follow this procedure: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/dev_guide/building.html

Comment: To obtain "dev builds" via pip or conda, you can also refer to http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/installation.html#developer-builds